# Converting Bitmap to ByteArray and back to Bitmap not working

Tags: android, bitmap

I tried to convert Bitmap to byteBuffer and then convert it back to Bitmap with the following code. No error occurs but the ImageView is unable to display anything on the screen. The image is 640 X 480 RGB jpeg.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/tower.jpg");

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

    Bitmap final_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageBitmap(final_bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting bitmap to byte array this way:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

And byteArray to bitmap as you do

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: I tried this method actually, and it worked. But why my first way of doing doesn't work?

Comment: @Pierrew if you use copyPixelsToBuffer, you need to use  copyPixelsFromBuffer() to restore it I think.

Comment: Stream contains the information about image size, etc (metadata) besides the pixels data.